# How can i get in exception occure,and in which method ,what is cause of that from the exception object?

Tags: java, android, exception

```
 public void showProgress() {
    try {
        if (progress == null)
            progress = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
        progress.setMessage("Please Wait..");
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
            progress.setMessage("Please Wait..");
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.show();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

I have have a lot of `try catch block` in my project. I have to send `className,methodName and cause of exception occur` in my project. Please suggest how? any convenient way?

Comment: Stack trace itself gives you all the information.  Not clear.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for ACRA or something similar, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614718/android-crash-report-doesnt-send-data-to-google-docs) for example

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter points out, the information is in the stacktrace output.

In addition, the `Throwable` class provides a `getStacktrace()` method that returns an array of `StackTraceElement` objects that gives the same information in a more convenient form.

And of course, the "cause" information (e.g. the exception name, message, and `cause` exception (if any)) can also be retrieved via other `Throwable` methods.

---

> I have have a lot of try catch block in my project ....

Well that is likely to be part of your problem.  If you attempt to catch, diagnose and recover from exceptions close to their source, you are liable to have to write lots of code.  It is often better to allow exceptions to propagate, and handle them at a higher level.

The second point is that you probably don't want to tell end-users about classes, methods, line numbers, etc.  The end user needs a non-scary and easy-to-understand error message, that (preferably) points to what the user did wrong and how to fix / avoid it.  The detailed information should be for developers / admins only, and for them full stacktrace (in the application's log file!) is the best option.